# How to override command of docker image in aws ecs in yaml

Tags: docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I dont know how to override default command of image.

```
ECSTaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
        -
          Name: "app"
          Image: "xxx/xxx:v1.0.2"
          Cpu: 128
          Memory: 128
          PortMappings:
          - ContainerPort: 80
          Essential: true
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !Ref LogsLogGroup
              awslogs-region: eu-west-1
              awslogs-stream-prefix: "app"
        -
          Name: "app-test-admin"
          Image: "xxx/xxx:v1.0.2"
          Cpu: 128
          Memory: 128
          PortMappings:
          - ContainerPort: 80
          Essential: true
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !Ref LogsLogGroup
              awslogs-region: eu-west-1
              awslogs-stream-prefix: "app-test-admin"
```

The dockerimage has default command `CMD ["npm", "start"]`. But in second container i would like to override with `npm run test-admin`

Comment: Have you tried this: [https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command)?

Comment: thanks, found solution.
`          Command: 
            -  npm
            -  run
           -   test-admin
`

Answer (score 0):

From the [Compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command):

> ## command
>
> Override the default command.
>
> ```
> command: bundle exec thin -p 3000
> ```
>
> The command can also be a list, in a manner similar to dockerfile:
>
> ```
> command: ["bundle", "exec", "thin", "-p", "3000"]
> ```